# Mac: JRE 7 crashes in 10.6.8 running threaded program

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I installed JDK 7 ("7u51") using Pacifist on my server running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and switched the main version to it in Java Preferences. I know that it's not supported by Oracle, but many do it and say that it works fine. It works, but if I try to launch my Bukkit server, it crashes after about 30 seconds. I get the following error messages:

```
java[34338:1707] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x115f8a3a0 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
java[34338:1707] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x115f8a3a0 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

I'm assuming it runs the code fine until it tries and fails to make a new thread. Same thing happens with JRE 8 and JRE 7u11. Any solutions?

Comment: Is JDK 7 even certified to run under Mac OS 10.6.8?

Comment: @Eric No… so much for "run on any platform". A lot of people have reported success installing it anyway.